# stored procedure to export to CSV with BCP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, export-to-csv, bcp

I need to create an on-demand export of user data on our website.  The user clicks an export button, classic ASP code executes a stored procedure that generates a file via BCP, and the user is prompted to download it.

I've created the sproc, and its working flawlessly when executed from SSMS. The catch is getting it to work from the site with the limited privileges granted to the account connecting to SQL from the website.  Here is a snippet:

```
    -- INSERT TEMP DATA
    INSERT INTO t_users_tempExport
        SELECT * FROM #tempExport

    -- show advanced options
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    RECONFIGURE

    -- enable xp_cmdshell
    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
    RECONFIGURE

    -- hide advanced options
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
    RECONFIGURE


-- EXPORT TO CSV
    DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
    SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * FROM DBNAME.dbo.tempExport WHERE scopeID='''+@randomString+'''" '
                    + 'queryout C:\temp\exportResidents_'+CONVERT(varchar(max),@userID)+'.csv -c -t, -T -S'
                    + @@servername
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql


-- RETURN FILE NAME
    SELECT 'C:\temp\export_'+CONVERT(varchar(max),@userID)+'.csv' AS fileName
```

The issue is that I cannot enable xp_cmdshell with the privledges granted to the account that is connecting to SQL from the website.  Im kind of at a loss as to how to proceed.

Is it possible to include the sysadmin credentials in the call to BCP?  Is there some easier option or work around?

Comment: Would it not be possible to call the BCP command from ASP instead of calling the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a completely different route.  I created the CSV file from pure ASP code, only using the sproc to return the data.